# Database Values displaying NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two databases.
Table 1 (Student) has  fields StudentID, EmployeeClass, StudentName. Here, EmployeeClass is varchar(5).
Table 2 (Employee) has fields EmployeeID, EmployeeName, Description, and EmployeeClass. Employee Class is nvarchar(5).

when i am writing Select Query as:

```
          SELECT S.StudentID, 
                 S.EmployeeClass, 
                 S.StudentName 
            FROM Student AS S
 LEFT OUTER JOIN Employee AS E
              ON CAST(S.EmployeeClass AS VARCHAR(5)) = E.EmployeeID
           WHERE E.Description = 'ABC'
```

All the values From employee table are showing as NULL? How to fix it

Comment: why would employee class == employee Id? that seems incorrect

Comment: Also don't compare numbers as strings - convert strings to numbers if you want to compare them with other numbers.

Comment: EmployeeID and EmployeeClass both nvarchar(5)

Comment: they might have the same type, but unless the columns are named incorrectly they seem to represent different things

Comment: Is it because EmployeeClass in Employee Table is nvarchar and EmployeeClass in Student table is varchar.. Does it make a difference ?

Comment: When looking at a statement like that, people would assume ID is an unique number - like a student number or incremental counter. Class would be something like "Masters" or "First Years" or "PD102". Unless the database naming convention is terrible.

Answer (score 0):

I think the join condition is wrong in your script.column 'EmployeeClass' refers to 'EmployeeID'  in your script.

```
SELECT S.StudentID, 
              S.EmployeeClass, 
              S.StudentName
 FROM Student AS S
  LEFT  JOIN Employee AS E
          ON cast(S.EmployeeClass  as varchar(5))= E.EmployeeClass 
             AND  E.Description = 'ABC'
```

Comment: What is the type  data type of employee class in both the tables?

Comment: first table its varchar(5)'= and second table nvarchar(5)

Comment: Yeah but its giving Null values in Employee Table

Comment: can you provide a sample data from both of you table..I am not sure why you are not getting the output.